# Silverlight: Individual visibility of a RowDetailsTemplate for each data row

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, silverlight-4.0

I'm trying to achive displaying the RowDetailsTemplate of a Silverlight `DataGrid` depending on a `bool` Property, bound to a `CheckBox` Control's `IsChecked` Property. Insinde of my RowDetailsTemplate there is a single custom `UserControl`, containing further Controls.

Since the `DataGrid` only allows a global setting (`RowDetailsVisibilityMode`) Some code-behind is needed. I've implemented a solution based on **[Rorys Reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471534/wpf-datagrid-rowdetailstemplate-visibility-bound-to-a-property/1473633#1473633)** (and using a behaviour-technique) which actually works.

Unfortunately, The `DataGrid` doesn't remember the individually shown or hidden Rows on sorting. The checkbox remains selected, but the Row collapses. Further, no event like "OnAfterSort" or something similar seems to exist, where i could "Refresh" the visibility settings in a loop.

Another idea was to bind the Visibility of my custom Details-`UserControl` to the CheckBox bound value. This actually works (when settings RowDetailsVisibilityMode to "Visible"), but I'm not able to get rid of this weird behaviour: When the CheckBox is checked, the Detail Template expands and the detail UserControl appears. Nice. When the CheckBox is unchecked again, the UserControl disappears (Visibility is set to `Collapsed`) but the Row doesn't collapse and the blank space remains (as it would be set to `Hidden` not `Collapsed`).

Do you have any ideas?

I hope it's ok I didn't post any code samples, the implementation is pretty easy and I believe that the problem doesn't actually lie in a coding mistake i made. You can setup a simple DataGrid quickly like in **[this perfect MSDN Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903938(v=VS.95).aspx)**. Starting from here, it's easy to test both described behaviours!

Really big thanks in advance,
- Thomas

Comment: You should post the link as answer so people can upvote, plus ppl don't have to read the whole question to find the answer.

Comment: Shimmy, the link posted does NOT lead to a final solution, it leads to code which can be used to simulate the wrong behavior. Looks like i wasn't clear enough, sorry